# Deploying Httpresponder locally in Linux using nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, nginx, passenger

I am very new to Ruby on Rails. I have been asked to deploy httpresponder locally from git (without Heroku).

Here is the link for the git repo:
https://github.com/aaronlerch/respond-to-it

I followed this tutorial here to guide me:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-passenger-and-apache-on-ubuntu-14-04#step-6-—-deploy

The following text is what I inserted in the testapp.config file:

```
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/respond-to-it-master/public
    RailsEnv development
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    <Directory "/home/rails/testapp/public">
            Options FollowSymLinks
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

When I restarted Apache I got the following error:

```
cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:430:in `activate_gem'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:297:in `block in run_load_path_setup_code'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:435:in `running_bundler'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:296:in `run_load_path_setup_code'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:100:in `preload_app'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:156:in `<module:App>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:30:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<main>'

Error ID
769d7537
```

It seems like the problem is with the Ruby I have installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to the problem. I had to update the gemfiles to the correct ruby and json versions.
Then I had to do a bundle install .

## Here are the steps that I followed:

**Navigate to the location of the source code:**

```
cd /var/www/html/respond-to-it-master/
```

**The ruby version in the Gemfile needs to be changed to the version installed on the computer:**

```
sudo nano Gemfile
```

**Update the version number to the following:**

```
ruby '2.3.0'
```

**Save the file (CTRL+X, Y, ENTER).**
**Now update the json version implemented by ruby:**

```
sudo nano Gemfile.lock
```

**Update the version number to the following:**

```
json (1.8.3)
```

**Run the following command to install the entire bundle:**

```
sudo bundle install
```

**Now the web-application will run locally.**